# How should variance in mock objects be handled?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

Let's say I have the following interface I want to mock:

**Searcher.java**

```
public interface Searcher {

    public String search();

    public void someMethod();

}
```

What do I do when I want to use different mock implementations for this interface? For example, in one test I would like to let the `search()` method return the empty string, in another test I would like it to start doing some HTTP requests etc.

Do I encapsulate the behaviour, like fx. putting it in a SearchBehaviour interface and then writing implementations for that interface:

```
public class SearcherMock implements Searcher {

    private SearchBehaviour searchBehaviour;

    public SearcherMock(SearchBehaviour searchBehaviour) {
        this.searchBehaviour = searchBehaviour;
    }

    @Override
    public String search() {
        return searchBehaviour.search();
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // Do something here
    }

}
```

Or do I create a new mock class for each mock implementation that varies? Fx. `EmptySearcher` and `HTTPSearcher`?

Comment: HTTP requests for unit tests? Sounds fishy given your interface (doesn't throw any kind of exception; what if the request fails?)

Comment: Nevermind the HTTP part, it was simply used for illustrating variance

Comment: I don't think you want to do that; a real mock will not run complex code. You will have it return the values you want so that the _users_ of that mock can be tested. Ie, with mockito you'd do `when(searcher.search()).thenReturn("something");`.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you use a java mocking tool such as [jMock](http://jmock.org/) or [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) which will save you some time by not letting you write the mockup tool yourself and instead writing good mockups :)

Using Mockito you could do something like this (not tested though):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

Searcher mockedEmptySearcher = mock(Searcher.class);

// define how empty searcher should behave
when(mockedList.search()).thenReturn("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that you can freely create anonymous inner classes for your different tests without using libraries:

```
@Test public void test1() {
  // When referring to outside local variables, they must be final.
  final AtomicBoolean someMethodCalled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  Searcher fakeSearcher = new Searcher() {
    @Override public String search() {
      return "stubbed return value";
    }

    @Override public void someMethod() {
      someMethodCalled.set(true);
    }       
  };
  SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest(fakeSearcher);
  systemUnderTest.pressBigRedButton();
  assertTrue("someMethod should have been called", someMethodCalled.get());
}
```

And even get to be pretty clever:

```
private Searcher createFakeSearcher(final String... searchResults) {
  return new Searcher() {
    int returnIndex = 0;

    @Override public String search() {
      return searchResults[returnIndex++];
    }

    @Override public void someMethod() {}       
  };
}
```

But some time invested learning a mocking framework will serve you and your tests well, because frameworks like Mockito were designed to strip away that boilerplate:

```
// Uses static imports from org.mockito.Mockito;
@Test public void test1() {
  Searcher mockSearcher = mock(Searcher.class);
  when(mockSearcher.search())
      .thenReturn("search one")
      .thenReturn("search two")
      .thenThrow(new IllegalStateException());

  SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest(mockSearcher);
  systemUnderTest.pressBigRedButton();
  verify(mockSearcher, times(2)).someMethod();
}
```

For a better conceptual introduction to *test doubles* (dummies/stubs/mocks/fakes) and the differences between them, read [Martin Fowler's article here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), or dive right into the [Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mock framework like Mockito and parameterize your test using JUnitParams.

Assuming you have a class that validates Searcher and if search returns 'valid' it will pass. The code and test would look like below, with 2 test cases, 1 for valid and one for invalid search result.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public boolean isValid(Searcher searcher) {
        return searcher.search().equals("valid");
    }
}

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    public Object[] provideIsValid() {
        return new Object[]{
                new Object[]{ "invalid", false },
                new Object[]{ "valid", true }
        };
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "provideIsValid")
    public void testIsValid(String output, String expected) {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        Searcher mock = mock(Searcher.class);
        when(mock.search()).thenReturn(output);

        String actual = someClass.isValid(mock);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: OP, note that JUnit4 has a built-in [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) runner, but [JUnitParams](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/) does offer a few more features. Either will work for the kind of variations you're asking about.